# window DOMContentLoaded or document DOMContentLoaded when fetching data?

Tags: fetch, window, addeventlistener, document, domcontentloaded

I'm currently writing a project that will need to fetch data from outside. My approach is when the event of `DOMContentLoaded` is fired, I will begin to fetch the data. But I'm kind of stuck on whether I should use the event `DOMContentLoaded` on `window` object or on `document` object. What are the differences and which is the better one?

My code below:

```
 async function getProducts() {
  try {
            const result = await fetch('./products.json');
            const data = await result.json();
            return data ;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
}
```

Should I use this one below:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  getProducts().then(//code that will render out the data on my web page);
});
```

Or should I use this one below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  getProducts().then(//code that will render out the data on my web page);
 
});
```

What are the differences and which approach is more appropriate?

I've seen this
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

but I still cannot figure out my question.